# MongoDB. How to find a string having all substrings?

Tags: php, mongodb, search, text, substring

I have **MongoDB** documents. All documents contain a fullname string (e.g. "john fidgerald kennedy", "john doe").

Upon a web query containing substrings (e.g. "john","kennedy" or "kennedy","john"), I would like to find all documents which fullname string contains all these substrings (e.g. "john fidgerald kennedy").

However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Basically, with PHP, I would like to do something like $collection->find(array("fullname" => "john" && "kennedy"). I know this syntax is not possible, but it's to give an idea of what I would like.

Any idea how to do that ? Ideally, I would like a fast method given that I have more than 1000000 documents.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: Honestly, reading the docs might help. You can either use [regexes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php) on the field or [create a full text search index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). Before that, you probably should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ESR's [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help you:

```
$query = "john";
$where = array(array('fullname'  => array('$regex' => new MongoRegex("/$query/i"))));
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();
$db = $mongoClient->selectDB("datbase_name");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("collection_name");
$cursor = $collection->find($where);
```